# How can I merge individual selected PDF files into one PDF upon download?

Tags: java, pdf, merge, download

How can I merge individual selected PDF files into one PDF upon download?

I want to achieve the following:
http://annualreport2010.landsecurities.com/create-your-own-report.aspx

Do I require an ASP website, or could I do something similar using a static HTML site?

Answer (score 5):

Static HTML won't do it.

You need something on the server side. The other answers have options that would work, I just wanted to also mention [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/), which you could then call from the server side. Be sure to escape all file names and such, though, because you would have to use system calls.

pdftk is really easy. The very first example from their [documentation](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/) shows how to merge several PDFs, named 1.pdf, 2.pdf and 3.pdf, into one PDF called 123.pdf:

```
pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf cat output 123.pdf
```

For PHP, there even is [pdftk-php](http://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2009/06/19/pdftk-php-officially-released/), if you want to look into that.

Answer (score 2):

See if itext can help in merging. A quick search gives many links - like  [Java: Merging multiple PDFs into a single PDF using iText.](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Java-Merging-multiple-PDFs-into-a-single-PDF-using-iText-671.php)

Answer (score 2):

I think that the Apache [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html) project can be good for you.

In particular, take a look at the [PDFMerger](http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandlineutilities/PDFMerger.html) class.

You can also use [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) but in my opinion it's less easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Java PDF merging software at http://codesforus.blogspot.com/.

p.s. They link to this download page: http://messiahpsychoanalyst.org/Documents/Downloads.html#part1

Answer (score 0):

You can find Source code for PDF split and Merge [Source forge PDF SAM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsam/)